# Kubernetes setup in different network

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

Is it possible to setup cluster with a different network?means master holds different ip and node holds different network ip.we will run kubeadm init on one network with host ip x.x.x.x and want to join using kubeadm join command on a node with host ip y.y.y.y.is it possible?if possible can you tell me what procedure needs to do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) especially the Before you begin section where it suggests you need to have a setup having full network connectivity , with private or public network.
Also , you need to have Pod network add-on such as Calico , flannel etc for connectivity between pods in your nodes, instruction for which is also detailed in the above link.

Comment: So,is it not possible?

Comment: if those two nodes do not have full network connectivity , how will they communicate?